# how to create text moving slider in bootstrap 3

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, css

I need create text moving slider in bootstrap theme. like this http://wpandsuch.com/posts/jquery-logo-slider-ticker/index.html

can you give me some sample tutorials or codes here
Thanks

Comment: given link is not working

Comment: edited link now it is working

Comment: http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a <...> tutorial <...> are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it." http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic